# How to Implement Object Level Access Control on External Tables in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a requirement where I need to implement object level access control in amazon redshift.
Consider a following scenario:

1. I have a schema 'xyz_schema' which is external and contains 3 external tables tbl1, tbl2, tbl3
2. Now these tables will be categorized into different subject areas sub1, sub2
3. The users will have access to these tables based on the subject area they are associated with

I want to implement this without changing the existing schema structure so that end user need not change their code wherever they referenced these tables. So I thought of creating schemas subject area wise and create views upon them in the existing schema 'xyz_schema' with the same name as the table. So I will create sub1, sub2 schemas and tbl1,tbl2 will be created in sub1 schema & tbl2,tbl3 will be created in sub2 schema. In the 'xyz_schema' we will create view as tbl1 which will point to sub1.tbl1 and tbl3 view which will point to sub2.tbl3

Now consider an scenario where tbl2 fall under both sub1 and sub2, so the above approach will not work for tbl2 as it falls under 2 different schemas.

Any alternative idea on how I can implement this will be very helpful.

I tried moving the tables to redshift internally but the requirement is to implement it on external tables and moving tables to redshift is not feasible.